# Exporting data map in JSON format through T-SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm trying to export a JSON format metadata file that describes my CSV. Here's what I have so far :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [ProjectID] AS [Project.ProjectID],
    [Study_Name] AS [Project.Study_Name],
    Gender.[Gender] AS [Gender.GenderLabel],
    Gender.GenderID AS [Gender.GenderID] 
FROM
    [ProjectTable] Project
JOIN 
    [Lkup].[Gender] Gender ON Project.Gender = Gender.GenderID
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

The output I see is a Gender body under every project but ideally I want all the projects I one and Gender shown only once.

The output from my code above:

```
{
  "Project":{
     "ProjectID":"112",
     "Study_Name":"Jul-Aug Study"
  },
  "Gender":{
     "GenderLabel":"Female",
     "GenderID":2
  }
},
{
  "Project":{
     "ProjectID":"112",
     "Study_Name":"Jul-Aug Study"
  },
  "Gender":{
     "GenderLabel":"Male",
     "GenderID":1
  }
}
```

The output I'm trying for :

```
{"Project": [
                    {
                        "ProjectID":"112",
                        "Study_Name":"Jul-Aug Study"
                    },
                    {
                        "ProjectID":"113",
                        "Study_Name":"Aug-Sept Study"
                    },
                    {
                        "ProjectID":"114",
                        "Study_Name":"Sept-Oct Study"
                    },

            ]
 },
 {"Gender": [
                    {
                        "GenderLabel":"Male",
                        "GenderID":1
                    },
                    {
                        "GenderLabel":"Female",
                        "GenderID":2
                    },
            ]
   }
```

It is my first-time exporting JSON so not sure if this structure is feasible to export from SQL Server but any ideas are most helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Your expected output is not valid JSON (it's missing some `}` characters). Please update it with valid JSON so we can help.

Comment: I edited to update the missing }